# Android emulator loads but not the program?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm pretty sure I have all the necessary installations. I created the AVD and tried to run one of the sample applications included in the SDK ("Jetboy"). When I hit run the program emulator starts up and eventually loads android but no applications start.

this is the output:

```
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] ------------------------------
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] Android Launch!
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] Performing com.example.android.jetboy.JetBoy activity launch
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - JetBoy] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2011-12-14 16:16:24 - Emulator] 
[2011-12-14 16:16:28 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2011-12-14 16:16:28 - JetBoy] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-12-14 16:16:28 - JetBoy] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-12-14 16:17:04 - JetBoy] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-12-14 16:17:04 - JetBoy] Uploading JetBoy.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-12-14 16:17:07 - JetBoy] Installing JetBoy.apk...
[2011-12-14 16:17:35 - JetBoy] Success!
[2011-12-14 16:17:35 - JetBoy] Starting activity com.example.android.jetboy.JetBoy on device emulator-5554
[2011-12-14 16:17:36 - JetBoy] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android.jetboy/.JetBoy }
```

Here is the logcat, as advised in comments below:

```
12-14 16:33:05.194: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 14070K/15047K, paused 35ms
12-14 16:33:05.214: I/dalvikvm-heap(539): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.801MB for 2073616-byte allocation
12-14 16:33:05.264: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 16095K/17095K, paused 4ms+5ms
12-14 16:33:05.594: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 10% free 16481K/18119K, paused 41ms
12-14 16:33:05.784: D/JetBoy(539): @@@ done creating view!
12-14 16:33:05.954: I/WindowManager(89): createSurface Window{416061c8 com.example.android.jetboy/com.example.android.jetboy.JetBoy paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-14 16:33:06.094: I/WindowManager(89): createSurface Window{41615788 SurfaceView paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-14 16:33:06.194: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 425K, 5% free 17308K/18119K, paused 58ms
12-14 16:33:06.224: I/dalvikvm-heap(539): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.776MB for 2926096-byte allocation
12-14 16:33:06.354: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 4% free 20159K/20999K, paused 54ms
12-14 16:33:06.475: D/gralloc_goldfish(539): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-14 16:33:06.614: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 20160K/20999K, paused 6ms+36ms
12-14 16:33:06.835: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2025K, 14% free 18135K/20999K, paused 35ms
12-14 16:33:06.894: I/dalvikvm-heap(539): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.583MB for 2926096-byte allocation
12-14 16:33:07.085: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 13% free 20992K/23879K, paused 17ms+5ms
12-14 16:33:07.554: I/ActivityManager(89): Displayed com.example.android.jetboy/.JetBoy: +4s900ms (total +42s207ms)
12-14 16:33:07.564: I/ActivityManager(89): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +42s215ms
12-14 16:33:07.594: V/PhoneStatusBar(143): setLightsOn(true)
12-14 16:33:08.984: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(89): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0) failed with errno -2
12-14 16:33:55.095: W/ThrottleService(89): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

2nd log, trying now with "Skeleton Application" as sample

```
12-14 16:50:28.033: I/DEBUG(33): debuggerd: Nov 23 2011 22:48:31
12-14 16:50:28.133: I/qemu-props(31): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
12-14 16:50:28.133: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
12-14 16:50:28.133: I/qemu-props(31): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
12-14 16:50:28.234: I/qemu-props(31): exiting (4 properties set).
12-14 16:50:28.283: I/Vold(30): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
12-14 16:50:28.313: I/Netd(32): Netd 1.0 starting
12-14 16:50:28.353: D/Vold(30): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
12-14 16:50:28.443: E/Netd(32): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
12-14 16:50:28.443: E/Netd(32): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
12-14 16:50:29.562: D/AndroidRuntime(36): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
12-14 16:50:29.562: D/AndroidRuntime(36): CheckJNI is ON
12-14 16:50:35.692: I/(37): ServiceManager: 0xf958
12-14 16:50:35.692: I/AudioFlinger(37): Loaded primary audio interface from LEGACY Audio HW HAL (audio)
12-14 16:50:35.692: I/AudioFlinger(37): Using 'LEGACY Audio HW HAL' (audio.primary) as the primary audio interface
12-14 16:50:35.692: D/AudioHardwareInterface(37): setMode(NORMAL)
12-14 16:50:35.702: I/CameraService(37): CameraService started (pid=37)
12-14 16:50:35.712: D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(37): Emulated camera list: 
12-14 16:50:35.712: D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera(37): Initialize: Fake camera is facing back
12-14 16:50:35.712: V/EmulatedCamera_Factory(37): 1 cameras are being emulated. Fake camera ID is 0
12-14 16:50:35.732: I/AudioFlinger(37): AudioFlinger's thread 0x10f60 ready to run
12-14 16:50:35.732: W/AudioFlinger(37): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service
12-14 16:50:35.742: I/AudioPolicyService(37): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
12-14 16:50:35.812: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger is starting
12-14 16:50:35.822: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
12-14 16:50:35.832: D/gralloc_goldfish(35): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): using (fd=11)
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): id           = 
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): xres         = 480 px
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): yres         = 800 px
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): xres_virtual = 480 px
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): yres_virtual = 1600 px
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): bpp          = 16
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): r            = 11:5
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): g            =  5:6
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): b            =  0:5
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): width        = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): height       = 123 mm (165.203247 dpi)
12-14 16:50:35.832: I/gralloc(35): refresh rate = 260.42 Hz
12-14 16:50:35.842: D/libEGL(35): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
12-14 16:50:35.842: D/libEGL(35): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGL informations:
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): # of configs : 8
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_ANDROID_swap_rectangle EGL_NV_system_time 
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): Client API: OpenGL ES
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): OpenGL informations:
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096 x 4096
12-14 16:50:35.862: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): flags = 000c0000
12-14 16:50:35.882: W/SurfaceFlinger(35): hwcomposer module not found
12-14 16:50:36.082: D/libEGL(72): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
12-14 16:50:36.082: D/libEGL(72): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-14 16:50:36.122: D/gralloc_goldfish(72): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-14 16:50:36.302: I/ARMAssembler(72): generated scanline__00000077:03010102_00000A01_00000000 [  9 ipp] (30 ins) at [0x40aa11e8:0x40aa1260] in 4108822 ns
12-14 16:50:36.322: I/ARMAssembler(72): generated scanline__00000077:03545402_00000A01_00000000 [ 31 ipp] (52 ins) at [0x40aa1268:0x40aa1338] in 1259607 ns
12-14 16:50:36.942: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(36): Profiling disabled.
12-14 16:50:36.992: I/Zygote(36): Preloading classes...
12-14 16:50:37.012: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 81% free 406K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-14 16:50:37.072: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 77% free 471K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 16:50:37.152: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 76% free 505K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:37.222: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 74% free 532K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:37.253: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 72% free 573K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:37.392: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 71% free 600K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:37.582: D/TextLayoutCache(36): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
12-14 16:50:37.612: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 70% free 631K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:37.622: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
12-14 16:50:37.752: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 16:50:37.752: D/MtpDeviceJNI(36): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
12-14 16:50:37.752: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 16:50:37.763: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 16:50:37.763: W/MediaProfiles(36): could not find media config xml file
12-14 16:50:37.763: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
12-14 16:50:37.763: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
12-14 16:50:37.792: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 68% free 667K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:38.202: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 53% free 962K/2048K, paused 19ms
12-14 16:50:38.292: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 42K, 51% free 1017K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms
12-14 16:50:38.443: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 49% free 1046K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 16:50:38.613: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 47% free 1094K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-14 16:50:38.702: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 44% free 1160K/2048K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-14 16:50:38.882: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 30% free 1439K/2048K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-14 16:50:38.892: W/Zyg
```

Comment: But the LogCat shows that it started the Activity

Comment: Your Console is ok..now check the logcat..to see logcat go to Eclipse->window->show view->other->android->logcat is it showing you any error?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added it to my original post. Is says there are some errors there. Any idea what they mean?

Comment: OK, I tried with a totally fresh project

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a while, but I found that my emulator target was too high for my application. Check that your emulator's API level is <= android:minSdkVersion in your manifest . Not a very helpful error message though is it?!

Answer (score 2):

emulator is not perfect... try going to the application menu i start it from there...
i have noticed sometimes it does not show up on its own.

Answer (score 2):

*`Starting activity com.example.android.jetboy.JetBoy on device emulator-5554`*
 line of logcat says that your avd tried to start your application. you can post more details from logcat. Restart your emulator, clean and build your project and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while I was working with a new App which used SQLite.

Anyways, the issue was that even after you close your Eclipse and Emulator.. in Task Manager the process adb.exe or abd.exe*32 was still running.

Steps:
1. Close eclipse and emulator.
2. Kill the process adb.exe or abd.exe*32.
3. Start your eclipse, clean build your app once and its almost like new.

Happy coding.

Comment: Not my question, so I can't mark as answer, but this is exactly what my issue was. Good catch; good answer. Thanks!