# Sensor Emulator in Android freezes ! WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using the Sensor Emulator from OpenIntents. I got 1 or 2 times to run the emulator on my pc but after that due to some errors in my program the Sensor Simulator stopped to work, the program simply freezes when I'm trying to start up the Sensor Emulator Library. An Android SDK new full installation or either a fresh Sensor Emulator installation doesn't solve the problem.
When I start the Android Emulator in DOS mode it says: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error.
On other Pc's this error doesn't appear and I assume that this error even when the Sensor Simulator worked didn't never appear. Any suggestions about how to get the Android Emulator to properly work again with the Sensor Emulator ??
I'm using Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So..I solved the issue after many hours of work. The problem was that the Sensors have not been disabled the first time as I run the SensorSettings program. To restore the program I opened the C:\Users\myuser.android\avd\myavd.avd\ folder ..and set to NO all the Sensor values located in the config.ini and in the hardware-qemu.ini files.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for launching the emulator from the command prompt. Then I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8499867/307716 which ended up completely eliminating any issues I had. Turns out starting it from the AVD manager was the best bet for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while I was working with a new App which used SQLite.

Anyways, the issue was that even after you close your Eclipse and Emulator.. in Task Manager the process adb.exe or abd.exe*32 was still running.

Steps:
1. Close eclipse and emulator.
2. Kill the process adb.exe or abd.exe*32.
3. Start your eclipse, clean build your app once and its almost like new.

Happy coding.

This may help : [Android emulator loads but not the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499813/android-emulator-loads-but-not-the-program/9727493#9727493)